# How to convert this text file into dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file[Univerity_towns.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZBO1.png) where the data is newline seperated but, I want two columns namely State and town but as the data is vertical, I just went:
   `df = pd.read_csv('university_towns.txt', delimiter= '\n', index_col=False, names = ["State", "RegionName"])`
 I get : [all the data in state column (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3m38.png) instead I want the code to differentiate between state and town, then fill respectively

Comment: You need to specify more details as what you are expecting. And also include your code/data as text.

Comment: Could you include your text file? We can't suggest how to convert it into a dataframe unless we have an idea of what your file looks like.

Comment: I made an edit to the question hopefully you can now understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got the data from WikiPedia and tried it out. If it's just a division of state and university names, I think it's possible with the following

```
 data = '''
 Alabama [edit]
 Auburn (Auburn University, Edward Via College of Osteopathic Medicine)[6]
 Birmingham (University of Alabama at Birmingham, Birmingham School of Law, 
 Birmingham Southern College, Cumberland School of Law, Miles Law School)[7]
 Dothan (Fortis College, Troy University Dothan Campus, Alabama College of Osteopathic Medicine)
 Florence (University of North Alabama)
 Homewood (Samford University)
 '''

 import pandas as pd
 import io

 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\n', header=None)
 df2 = df[0].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)

 df2
          0     1
 0  Alabama [edit]
 1  Auburn  (Auburn University, Edward Via College of Oste...
 2  Birmingham  (University of Alabama at Birmingham, Birmingh...
 3  Dothan  (Fortis College, Troy University Dothan Campus...
 4  Florence    (University of North Alabama)
 5  Homewood    (Samford University)
```

Comment: In the previous example, the first space is used as the base, but it can't be helped if the state and city names are in the same column. I couldn't help you.

Comment: I need two columns one of state other of cities and everything inside bracket does not matter.So dataframe should be like: {('Alabama','Auburn'),('Alabama',' Birmingham'),('Alabama','Dothan') so on }